# C++ - skip to next iteration on enter

Tags: c++17, cin, enter

I'm trying to read values from user input, integer values, inside a for-loop. I need for the loop to skip current iteration when the user presses enter. Something like this.

```cpp
short value;
for(short i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << "Enter value. If you don't feel like it, press enter.";
    cin >> value;
    if(value is different from ENTER)
        cout << "did something with " << i << endl;
    else{ //off to next iteration
        cout << "did nothing with " << i << endl;
    }
}
```

sample run:

```
//input for size = 3
15Enter
Enter
34Enter

//output
did something with 0
did nothing with 1
did something with 2
```

I have seen in many places that `cin` is not the best candidate for this, but I have not found an example I can apply to reading integers, not strings.

Note: I don't really want to validate that it's an integer being input, I just need to know if it's just an ENTER and ignore it and move on to the next iteration.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use: continue

When you use continue, the current loop is skip.

In if you can do: if(value!='\n'){...}

\n is ENTER

Edit:

```
for(short i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            cout << "Enter value. If you don't feel like it, press enter.";
            if(cin.get()!='\n'){
                cout << "did something with " << i << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else{ //off to next iteration
                continue;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry but this does not work, if press **23Enter** it evaluates `value!='n'` to `true` but if press **Enter**, it just keeps on waiting for it until an "actual" value is input

Comment: use cin.get() function to catch '\n' and later you have to clear and ignore cin.

Comment: how can I use `value` in your edit? I need it to store the input number